# cs50 credit loop problem to divide the number

Tags: c, cs50

I was on the CS50 credit problem. I was trying to find the number’s second-to-last digit. For example,`4003600000000014`.It should be `4,0,6,0,0,0,0,1`.
I am confused by this loop. When I use numbers e.g.`1,2,...15` to replace  `2i-1`, it worked. But in this loop, it did not work. It gave me `6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6`
Thank you for your help!

`

```
long answer=get_long("Number: ");
int i;
long a;

for (i=1; i<9 ; i++)
{
    a= fmod((answer / (pow(10,2i-1))),10);
    printf("%ld\n",a)
}
```

`

Comment: Re: "it did not work", well you should explain what it did.

Comment: If you want to multiply `i` by 2, you need to use the multiplication operator `*` i.e. `2i-1` should be `2*i-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `2i-1` isn't what you think it is.

`2i` is actually a complex number constant.  When you then pass the complex value `2i-1` to `pow`, the imaginary part gets truncated and the actual value passed is `-1`.

When multiplying two numbers / variables, you have to use the `*` operator:

```
2*i-1
```

Comment: @李Jojo glad I could help.  Feel free to accept this answer if you found it useful.